# How to Replace Existing Format in Sheet1 using ThisWorkbook BeforeSave

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have this code below that performs formatting whenever the cells are empty.

```
If cell is NULL
   Fill Green
If cell is not NULL
   Remove Fill

For i = 1 To 9


 With Target.Offset(0, i)
                    .Locked = False
                    .FormatConditions.Delete
                    .Value = ""
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISBLANK(" & Target.Offset(0, i).Address & ")"
                    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
                        .SetFirstPriority
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                    End With
                End With
            Next i
```

Now my problem is that I would like to change the color of the cell from GREEN to RED once the user save this excel document with missing values on the mandatory cells (green cells)

I have this code in ThisWorkbook.

```
For j = 2 To 10
     If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
                *'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3*
                errcnt = errcnt + 1
     End If
Next j
```

This code `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3` is currently not working. I also tried to add `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).FormatConditions.Delete` before this code, but that is still not working

Comment: why is it not working? Is there an error? Or is it just not coloring cells?

Comment: @gizlmeier im getting a runtime error. It seems that we cannot replace a existing format using this one unless we delete first the existing format

Comment: Formatting conditional formatted cells works fine for me after i deleted the conditional formatting

Comment: @gizlmeier can you share your code used?

Comment: I just set up a simple Conditional Formatting with greater than... Now, if I use `.FormatConditions.Delete` on that cell, the formatting is gone, and after that I can use `.Interior.Color = vbRed` for example

Comment: @gizlmeier it's not working on me :(

Answer (score 0):

The following code will remove exisiting Conditional Formatting from a cell:

```
With Target.Offset(0, i)
    .Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
End With
```

Comment: still not working on me, I cant use target on BeforeSave

Comment: If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Select
                Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If

Comment: where are you getting an error on your posted code, it's working when I test it on my PC.